# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)

Tags: python, json

My function looks like this:

```
filename = 'orderbook_file.json'

def get_line():
    f = open(filename, 'r')

    n_display = 0

    for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
        print(data)
        #if n_display % 100: continue
        n_display +=1
    return data
```

My json object like this:

```
[
{ 
    "asks" : [
        [
            0.00276477, 
            NumberInt(9)
        ]
    ], 
    "bids" : [
        [
            0.002755, 
            NumberInt(544)
        ]
    ], 
    "lastUpdated" : 1538582700048.0
},
{ 
    "asks" : [
        [
            0.00276477, 
            NumberInt(9)
        ]
    ], 
    "bids" : [
        [
            0.002755, 
            NumberInt(544)
        ]
    ], 
    "lastUpdated" : 1538582700048.0
}
]
```

I received the error which is in the title when I try to load the json. The file is basically a an array of json objects. I am not really familiar with Json, any help? thanks!

Comment: Try putting the JSON through a JSON formatter/pretty printer.  I suspect your JSON is malformed.  In fact I'm not sure which JSON parser this site uses: https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print but it chokes on that `NumberInt(9)` line.

Comment: even if the JSON is right the program won't work, you are feeding each line to `json.loads()`which is not valid JSON. simply use `json.load()` function to load the file if the file contain the correct JSON.

Comment: @VishalSingh then I have the following error message `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: @Viktor.w assuming you will correct your JSON, `json.load(f)` will work. `json.load` accepts file object.